# add/remove/toggle elements onClick without duplicating

Tags: jquery, html

In this scenario i am clicking a table cell which is collection a row id and cell value and creating a

element dynamically and putting row id and cell values to it. But the problem is when click event is fired on a particular cell twice its duplicating the

element.Is there a way to remove duplicate element when click twice.? like If some one click on a cell once it add

and click twice it remove

not duplicate.

(Sorry for my bad English i hope you understand this problem.)

Here is HTML TABLE

```
    <table border="1" width="200px" id="grid">
    <tr id="101">
        <td class="left"><span>10</span><br/><a>5690</a></td>
        <td class="right"><span>656</span><br/><a>5645</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="102">
        <td class="left"><span>11</span><br/><a>545</a></td>
        <td class="right"><span>525</span><br/><a>564564</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="103">
        <td class="left"><span>6565</span><br/><a>56456</a></td>
        <td class="right"><span>5456</span><br/><a>56465</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="content"></div>
```

And here is Jquery

```
$("#grid td.left").click(function() {
                var itemid = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
                var currentrate = $(this).find("span").text();
                var offeredammount = $(this).find("a").text();

                $(".content").after("<p style='background-color:#F0F8FF'>" + itemid + " " + currentrate + " " + offeredammount + "</p>");
            });
```

Live Example

http://jsfiddle.net/re5fohdq/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give a class to created p tag and play with it like this

```
$("#grid td.left").click(function() {
var itemid = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");

if($('.p-'+itemid).length ){
  $('.p-'+itemid).remove();
}else{
var currentrate = $(this).find("span").text();
var offeredammount = $(this).find("a").text();
$(".content").after("<p style='background-color:#F0F8FF' class='p-"+itemid+"'>" 
 + itemid + " " + currentrate + " " + offeredammount + "</p>");
 }        
});
```

here is the working fiddle

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/re5fohdq/9/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this : put id to `p` tag while adding it and check if it exist or not and add / remove accordingly.

```
    $("#grid td.left").on("click", function() {
        var itemid = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
        var currentrate = $(this).find("span").text();
        var offeredammount = $(this).find("a").text();

        var alreadyExist = $("p[id='"+itemid+"']").length;

        if(alreadyExist>0)
        {
            $("p[id='"+itemid+"']").remove();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".content").after("<p style='background-color:#F0F8FF' id='"+itemid+"'>" + itemid + " " + currentrate + " " + offeredammount + "</p>");
        }
   });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/re5fohdq/15/)**

Answer (score 0):

update your script with the below:

**Updated Script**

```
$("#grid td.left").click(function () {
    $(".content").empty();
    var itemid = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
    var currentrate = $(this).find("span").text();
    var offeredammount = $(this).find("a").text();    
    $(".content").append("<p style='background-color:#F0F8FF'>" + itemid + " " + currentrate + " " + offeredammount + "</p>");
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/re5fohdq/7/)

Comment: this will remove all previously selected rows, and will add only clicked one.

Comment: sorry I missed out, then $("#grid td.left").one("click", function() will be the correct one!!, thanks for correcting me!